# SWIFT: Passing Data from one class to another

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

So I have been using prepareForSegue to pass data from one variable to another class. It all works fine when the variable I am passing data to is with the destinationViewController. But what happens when it's not?

Example: I am taking moving from ViewController1 to ViewController2 but I want the data from ViewController1 to go to a "non ViewController" class even though I still want the segue to VC2 to happen.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "stopRecording") {
            //let playSoundsVC:PlaySoundsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaySoundsViewController
            let audioEffectsClass = AudioEffect()
            let data = sender as! RecordedAudio
            audioEffectsClass.receivedAudio = data
        }
    }
```

import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AudioEffect {

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine!
var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode!
var audioFile: AVAudioFile!
var receivedAudio: RecordedAudio!
var changeEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()


func create(){
    //output is through speakers

    do{
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
    } catch {print("Failed output audio through speakers.")}

    audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)


}

func playAudio(){
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.reset()
    do {
        audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: receivedAudio.filePathUrl)
    } catch {print("Failed to create file.")}

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {}
    audioPlayerNode.play()

    audioEngine.attachNode(changeEffect)
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changeEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(changeEffect, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)
}

func playAudioWithVariablePitch(pitch:Float) {
    changeEffect.pitch = pitch
    create()
    playAudio()
}

func playAudioWithVariableRate(rate: Float){
    changeEffect.rate = rate
    create()
    playAudio()

}

func stopAudio(){
    audioEngine.stop()
}
```

}

Comment: Could you give us some code?

Comment: Can you provide a code example of the "other class" along with a description of how you intend to use it?

Comment: Added code. Sorry for not adding sooner.

Comment: @Neo updated the code

Comment: hat do you expect? you create the object `audioEffectsClass` as a local variable. as soon as the if-clause reaches it's end, `audioEffectsClass` will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable referencing the class, make a method to receive the data in that class and call the method and pass the data in `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope I understand you right... But if I understand you right I don´t know what should be the problem?!? If you pass data to a subclassed UIViewcontroller class, or to any other class, its just the same?!? :-)

What error do you get? Or what happens if you run your code posted?

Maybe this helps you?

```
class VCOne: UIViewController {

    lazy var audioEffect: AudioEffect = AudioEffect()

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "stopRecording") {
            if let recordedAudio: RecordedAudio = sender as? RecordedAudio {
                audioEffect.receivedAudio = recordedAudio
            }
        }
    }

}

class AudioEffect {
    var receivedAudio: RecordedAudio?
}
```